# Mojave (10.14) setting environment variables

Tags: mojave, environment-variables

There are other questions and topics just like this but I can not find anything that is specific to 10.14 Mojave.  I have tried the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist` method and I have tried to move the same file to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` (and restarted) but it does not affect Emacs when it is launched from the dock, Spotlight, or the Applications window.

In that file, I did `launchctl setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin`  Curiously, when Terminal (bash) is launched and `echo $PATH > /tmp/bash.debug` is the first line in `~/.bash_profile`, the output is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` so... something has prepended `/usr/local/bin` while I was attempting to append it.

I have not tried things like `/etc/launchd.conf` or `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` because the pages I find say that both of those stopped working a while back.

In particular, I want to add `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH`.  Currently, my work around is to do it in my Emacs start up files.

There was one person who mentioned that setting system wide environment variables in MacOS is a bad idea and I'm tempted to go along with that.  The Emacs specific solution I have works and doesn't have any side effects.  But, I'd like to know how to do it ... if it is possible.  Once I get curious about something its hard for me to let it go.

As always, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: See this thread: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/emacs-and-command-line-path-disagreements-on-osx/10735#10735  look for user4669748' article

Comment: @historystamp you should give the link direct to the answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20425/9874

Comment: @historystamp That does not work for me.  If I do: ps -Eef | grep '/Finder ' | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '^PATH='  I get the output of PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin . That is getting the environment that the Finder has set.  I'm assuming that the Finder is what launches applications.

Comment: I have "EmacsForMacOS" and it uses a Ruby script to start up.  Perhaps that is causing the issue.  I will investigate this.

Comment: I thought perhaps ruby was altering the environment before entering the script that is passed to it but from my testing that is not the case.  Currently, no matter what I do, PATH is set to /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin when Emacs is spawned from the Finder.

Comment: Another user has commented that adding or changing the global environment on Macos is asking for trouble.  I've currently modified my emacs start up to add the paths I need.  This is likely a better solution for multiple reasons.  I'm still curious if and how you can modify the environment of processes spawned by the Finder on Macos.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this one in Mojave is to create a named file in `/etc/paths.d`, for instance

```
vi /etc/paths.d/local_bin
```

Put

```
/usr/local/bin
```

in the file, save and quit. Start another terminal window and it will be on your path.

I have one for MacPorts

```
$ cat MacPorts 
/opt/local/bin
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but it appears from my testing that adding entries like you suggest is the same as adding lines to /etc/paths ... its curious that they have both.  Adding lines takes affect immediately for new bash shells but processes spawned by Finder (the GUI) still has PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin ...

Comment: In case it may be helpful to others, I had errors with permissions in the /etc/paths.d folder. I got around it by duplicating an existing file from etc/paths.d, renamed it, and moved it outside the folder (to avoid permissions trouble), replaced its content with the paths I wanted to add, then finally moved it to the /etc/paths.d folder. Good luck.

Comment: @pedz: "its curious that they have both." – `/etc/paths.d/*` makes it much easier for machines to add/remove paths. It is easier for a machine to create and delete files than to figure out how to edit them.