# How to add permanent environment variable in zsh

Tags: macos, mojave, python, zsh, environment-variables

I have been scouring the internet, and cannot seem to find a solution to permanently adding an environment variable, specifically when my OS is macOS Mojave (10.14).  It seems there are a lot of tutorials for past versions of the OS, but none for this one one.  It also seems every old method has become outdated.

I want to add an environment variable `ENV_VAR=12345` to my Mac, so that I can import it into a Python module using `os.environ['ENV_VAR']`

The most relevant tutorial I have found is [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345441/mojave-10-14-setting-environment-variables), but it doesn't quite do the trick for me. A lot of others tell you how to temporarily add environment variables to bash, but I don't think this is good enough.  I want the addition to be there if you restart terminal.

Can you please either provide a short tutorial or point me to the correct/modern tutorial?

**UPDATE**: I should have mentioned that I use `zsh`.  This was key.

Comment: Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346336/why-have-both-bash-profile-and-bashrc and/or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48870/global-bash-profile to persist environment variables.

Comment: Is the python script run from the command line or us an app run from desktop or finder?

Comment: @Mark the script is run from the command line! Via `python -m module_name`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is unclear as the shell is zsh which is not mentioned. The tutorials etc are for a different case. If the question was I use zsh and how do I set a environment variable for python then OK The question and answers will just confus anyone new reading them

Answer (score 109, accepted):

#### Bash

Since Bash is typically the default shell you can open up this file in your home directory:

```
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
```

And add your variable to this file:

```
export ENV_VAR=12345
```

You can do this without even having to edit this file if you like, using the following one-liner:

```
$ echo 'export ENV_VAR=12345' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And then confirm like so:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
for i in ~/.bash_profile.d/[0-9]*; do
  . "$i"
done
export ENV_VAR=12345
```

After doing the above, if you open a new terminal you should see that environment variable has been set:

```
$ echo $ENV_VAR
12345
```

#### Zsh

If you find that you're using an alternative shell such as `zsh`, that uses a different set of configuration files maintained within your home directory, `~`. Luckily the syntax of the changes is basically the same, just different files. So you can add the above example to this file instead:

```
$ echo 'export ENV_VAR=12345' >> ~/.zshenv
```

And then when you launch a `zsh`:

```
$ echo $ENV_VAR
12345
```

#### References

- [Zsh Startup Files](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html)

Comment: Note: If you want an ENV to be accessible outside of something launched from a shell context, like when running a Python script directly, setting it in your bash/zsh config files won't solve it.  You'd need to use `launchctl setenv ENV_NAME ENV_VALUE` to make it available everywhere.  See my other answer for more info.

Comment: In MacOS Monterey, I don't have `zshenv` under user's dir nor under `/etc`. Thus I'm using `$ echo 'export ENV_VAR=12345' >> ~/.zshrc` to inject this environment variable.

Answer (score 42):

First, execute in a terminal with zsh (Z Shell):

```
echo 'export ENV_VAR=12345' >> ~/.zshenv
```

Then, reload changes:

```
source ~/.zshenv
```

Finally, test if your new variable is set:

```
echo $ENV_VAR
```

**Note:** 
By standard, the `.zshenv` file should only contain environment variables setting commands. `.zshenv` is sourced on all invocations of the shell, hence it will persist even after you restart your machine.

Comment: Maybe a bit obvious for experts but the `source` command did the trick for me and I didn't even have to reopen another terminal. (as opposed to the accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

The other solutions describe how to set an environment variable in all your zsh/bash shell instances.  But they don't set a permanent ENV that's available everywhere on in macOS, including in every launched program.

For example, if you define `ENV_VAR=1` your `.zshrc` but you launch Python directly without launching it from a shell, then anything set in your `.zshrc` wouldn't be available in `os.environ['...']`.

To solve this, you can set a truly global environment variable on macOS at the system wide level using `launchctl` like this:

```sh
launchctl setenv "ENV_VAR" "12345"
```

After running that, every newly launched program will see the `ENV_VAR` environmental variable, including shell instances as well as things launched without a shell. You will need to close your terminal app and re-open for it to be in your shell. It also won't show up in ssh sessions, which aren't launched by launchd like GUI programs.

Update: It seems that this does not persist across system restarts.  You can find some discussion for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite). Funnily, a decent solution to this is just to put `launchctl setenv ...` in your shell's  `.zshenv` or `.bash_profile`.  Though that means you'll need a launch a shell before the global vars are set, so you can see some more [robust solutions that involve creating a new launchd job here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/142318).

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I use [this](https://gist.github.com/blizzrdof77/4f808949037cbb69460763a638be4aec) portable shell [function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05) to quickly *set* & *permanently add* [`environment variables`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Assignment).

I predominantly use [`zsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), but it can be easily adapted for [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) or other [`POSIX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant shells.

```sh
# -----------------------------------------
#  Create permanent environment variable
#
#  $1 - variable name
#  $2 - variable definition
#  @requires: '~/.zshrc' or '~/.bashrc'
# -----------------------------------------
function new_env_var {
  local detected_shell="$(ps -o comm= -p $$)"
  local rcfile=$(echo "${HOME}/.${detected_shell//-/}rc")
  if [[ -f $rcfile ]]; then
    local var_name; local var_val
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      echo "variable name (e.g. 'NEW_VAR' for '\$NEW_VAR'):"; read var_name
    else
      var_name=$1
    fi
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
      echo "variable definition:"; read var_val
    else
      local s2 var_val="${@//${var_name}/}"
      until s2="${var_val#[   ]}"; [ "$s2" = "$var_val" ]; do var_val="$s2"; done
    fi
    echo "export $var_name=\"$var_val\"" >> $rcfile; export $var_name="$var_val"
  else
    echo "No $detected_shell runcom file found. Please make sure $rcfile exists."
  fi
}
```

**You can use it like so**:
  **‣**  `new_env_var MY_ENV_VAR 9,999`

Answer (score 2):

shows all hidden files like .bash_profile and .zshrc
`$ ls -a`

Starting with macOS Catalina, macOS uses zsh instead of bash for newly created accounts.

Check which shell running:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/zsh
```

```
$ cd $HOME
$ open -e .zshrc
```

or if using vim

```
$ vi .zshrc
```

Then add it like this

```
$ export my_var="/path/where/it/exists"
$ export PATH=$PATH:/$my_var/bin
```

For example: if installed app named: myapp in /Applications
Then

```
export MYAPP_HOME=/Applications/myapp
export PATH=$PATH:$MYAPP_HOME/bin
```

or shortcut

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/myapp/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The file names used to set environment variables differ depending on which shell you use.  By default, the mac assigns the bash shell to new users.  `echo $SHELL` if unsure.

From here, check the man page.  e.g.: `man bash` and it will document the files it will execute at runtime.  You can add an environment variable to one of those files.

For bash, make sure you `export` the variable or it wont be inherited by a child process.  e.g.: `export ENV_VAR=12345` or `ENV_VAR=12345; export ENV_VAR`

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**: read the comments to @slm's answer.  I should have been editing `~/.zshrc` not `~/.bash_profile`, because I use zsh.  The more you know!  The below answer also seemed to work, but hacky.

---

Thanks to @Tim Campbell and @slm, I was able to get something working.

*Background*

`echo $0` outputs `-zsh`

`echo $SHELL` outputs `/bin/zsh`

`echo $PATH` outputs `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

---

*My "Hacky" Solution*

I made a shell script `configure_env.sh` and put in in `~/Documents`

```
#!/bin/zsh
export ENV_VAR=12345
```

I then ran `chmod +x ~/Documents/configure_env.sh`

I then did `nano ~/.bash_profile` and appended `source ~/Documents/configure_env.sh`

Then, when I typed `echo $ENV_VAR`, it returned `12345`

:) thank you again to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Ugh this is a mess and a dredful idea- you need to edit one file only and add `export ENV_VAR=12345
` to it and the file is .zshrc So delete everything after  I use zsh. ALso the fact you are using zsh must be in the question